# Google Maps - TileOverlay - Stretch tiles for higher zoom levels

Tags: android, google-maps, maptiler

I have built a custom TileProvider from a map image, but the original image does not cover the required map area for the resolution corresponding to the highest zoom level. 
By default, the provider returns no tiles if I do not create images for the corresponding zoom levels. Is it possible to zoom on the existing tile rather? I could create zoomed tiles these which would be basically stretched and cut versions of the highest resolution I have, but this seems redundant and would take unnecessary disk space/processing.

Is there a way to stretch tiles when none is available for a high zoom level, rather than creating those tiles explicitly? I could always set the maxZoom property on the map, but I have different overlays with different resolutions. I could also add some smart processing in the provider to return a subsampled version of a tile at lower resolution on the fly, but I am hoping there is a built in way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot stretch the tiles per zoom level (automatically) but you can instead wrap your URL Tile provider with one that allows you to customize the behaviour. For example I've done (some years ago) a custom tile provider whose cached the tiles in a specific folder of the phone (better and longer caching than gmaps one), but could also be possibile to check the zoom (z) and if it is higher than a specific value, you can retrieve the tile for a lower zoom and split by 4 (no zoom but cut and zoom.
The result will be very poor, and honestly I find better to create them on server side (are you using a WMS provider maybe?).

Comment: Yes this is the fallback approach I was considering. Result won't be great but as my bitmap doesn't cover full resolution anyway I prefer having a stretched image than no image. Seems like that's the way to go then thanks